# Python regex numbers into string

Tags: python, regex

There is a string expression like this

```
example, example, -1,2
example, example/example, 9,9
```

-1,2 and 9,9 are a float numbers

How can i separate string and float statements here?

When tries the statement below, separates the string and float statements separately.However, there are problems in expressions such as -1,2 -9,0.

```
import re

...

print(re.split(r'\s+(?=\d)|(?<=\d)\s+', txt))


output:
['example, example -1,0']
['example, example/example', '9,9']

....
```

Comment: You may actually use `res = "example, example, -1,2".rpartition(" ")` and get `res[0]` and `res[-1]`

Comment: Can you share some of the actual data?

Comment: who is "he"...?

Comment: @MohitC my english is bad.

Comment: Based on your first examples, it doesn't need a regex. `str.split(', ')` does the same thing – your float is then item [-1] as well. But I don't know why your last example "-1,2 -9,0" doesn't use the same comma+space separation. If your data is not reliable in this, you may want to add that to the first list of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import re
from typing import Union

txt = """example, example, -1,2
example, example/example, 9,9
"""


def parse_floats(input_text: str) -> Union[float, str]:
    try:
        return float(input_text.replace(",", "."))
    except:
        return input_text


for line in txt.splitlines():
    elements = [parse_floats(element) for element in re.split(r",\s+", line.strip())]
    print(elements)
```